# position of UIScrollView getting changed when Orientation is changing in ipad twice

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, orientation

The scrollview is changing its position automatically when I switch to landscape and portrait modes more than one time while scrolling the scrollview.

What else I have to do...to retain its position in the same manner as it was loaded for the first time. I would like to scroll horizontally all the time in landscape mode and always vertical in portrait mode.

The below code is just I'm using:

```
UIScrollView * myBookScrollView = [[MyBooksScrollView alloc] init];
myBookScrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
myBookScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;       
myBookScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:myBookScrollView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to  set it's autoresizingMask? Setting it to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth might help.